# Need help in using REGEXP function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT ID,
     CASE WHEN listagg(
            DISTINCT col_1,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY col_1)= '' THEN 'null' 
            ELSE (lower(LISTAGG(distinct col_1,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY col_1))) END AS Col_001
        FROM 
            (SELECT distinct B.ID, date, timestamp, 
            TRY_CAST(pno as INTEGER) as pno,
            REGEXP_REPLACE(col_1,'\http.*$|null', '') as col_1
            FROM 
            table1 B LEFT JOIN table2 D ON D.ID=B.ID
            WHERE B.ID IN('5871162','35915895')
            and date='2021-11-02'
            ORDER BY pno) 
            GROUP BY ID;
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results like

```
ID                 COL_001

5871162            ,monthend_offer
35915895           dec_cashback,dec_offer
```

If I replace comma with empty string, the result will be like mentioned below and that is not the excepted result

```
    5871162            monthend_offer
    35915895           dec_cashbackdec_offer
```

I want to replace only the comma ',' from the first record. The record should display like below:

```
5871162            monthend_offer
35915895           dec_cashback,dec_offer
```

I want to replace only the LEADING comma

Any guidance on how to implement this?

Comment: By mistake deleted the answer which someone replied. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you can just use another regex.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col_1,'\http.*$|null', '')),',','',1,1) as COL1;
```

1 for where regex starts and another 1 how many should he replace.

Hope that helps

Comment: I have tried the logic you said but still showing the same result.

Comment: @Jenifer Yeah sorry I misread your problem. My solution won't work in your situation. Simeon solution is the right one. My bad

Answer (score 2):

To trim a string you can:

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    ltrim(column1, ','),
    regexp_replace(column1, '^,')
FROM VALUES
    (',monthend_offer'),
    ('dec_cashback,dec_offer');
```

But the reason you have the problem is you have an empty string in `col_1` which is getting rolled up in your listagg.

The CASE statement (this one:)

```
   CASE 
        WHEN listagg(DISTINCT col_1,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY col_1)= '' THEN 'null' 
        ELSE lower(LISTAGG(distinct col_1,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY col_1)) 
    END AS Col_001
```

can be written as:

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(lower(LISTAGG(distinct column2,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column2)),''),'null') as Col_001
```

As seen in:

```
SELECT column1,
    IFNULL(NULLIF(lower(LISTAGG(distinct column2,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column2)),''),'null') as smaler,
    CASE 
        WHEN listagg(DISTINCT column2,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column2)= '' THEN 'null' 
        ELSE lower(LISTAGG(distinct column2,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column2)) 
    END AS Col_001
from values 
    (1,''),
    (2,'dec_cashback'),
    (1,'monthend_offer'),
    (2,'dec_offer')
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

| COLUMN1 | SMALER | COL_001 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ,monthend_offer | ,monthend_offer |
| 2 | dec_cashback,dec_offer | dec_cashback,dec_offer |